# What Web2py app size to deploy on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, web2py

Am new to web2py, GAE, I've developed a web2py app that has an access to large database ~ 2GB. I wonder how will this be since GAE details that the app size should be 100Mb.
Will I have to have a server to access the DB? I would like to know before a plan my test app.

Comment: unclear what you ask.db size and app size are different concepts.

Comment: Also, where do you see that GAE app size is limited to 100Mb?